# Java: Array Index Out of Bound Exception

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

When I compiled I got here error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. I checked code 3 times and no error found there, also I am not writing after end of array.

```
Random nahoda = new Random();    int[][] minPol = new int[5][5];
int[][] cisPol = new int[5][5];
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
minPol[i][j] = nahoda.nextInt(2);
cisPol[i][j] = 0;
}
}
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        if(minPol[i][j]!=0)
        {
        if(i != 0 || j != 0 || i != 4 || j != 4)
        {
            cisPol[i+1][j+1]++;
            cisPol[i+1][j-1]++;
            cisPol[i-1][j+1]++;
            cisPol[i-1][j-1]++;
            cisPol[i+1][j]++;
            cisPol[i-1][j]++;
            cisPol[i][j+1]++;
            cisPol[i][j-1]++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                {
                    cisPol[i+1][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i+1][j]++;
                }
                else if(j == 4)
                {
                    cisPol[i+1][j]++;
                    cisPol[i+1][j-1]++;
                    cisPol[i][j-1]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cisPol[i+1][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i+1][j]++;
                    cisPol[i+1][j-1]++;
                    cisPol[i][j-1]++;
                }
            }
            else if(i == 4)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                {
                    cisPol[i-1][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i-1][j]++;
                    cisPol[i][j+1]++;
                }
                else if(j == 4)
                {
                    cisPol[i-1][j-1]++;
                    cisPol[i-1][j]++;
                    cisPol[i][j-1]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cisPol[i][j-1]++;
                    cisPol[i][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i-1][j+1]++;
                    cisPol[i-1][j]++;
                    cisPol[i-1][j-1]++;
                }
            }
        }            
        }
    }
}
```

I am beginner in Java and thanks for tips

Comment: At which line of your code do you get this Exception?

Comment: when i=4 or j=4„ the index goes out of bounds because of i+1 or j+1 indexes respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this condition:

```
if(i != 0 || j != 0 || i != 4 || j != 4)
```

That doesn't do what you want it to. It will *always* be true, because `i` can't be simultaneously equal to 0 and 4.

Therefore you'll end up going into here when `j` is 0:

```
cisPol[i+1][j-1]++;
```

Bang.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

Replace this line;

```
 if(i != 0 || j != 0 || i != 4 || j != 4)
```

with

```
 if( i>=1 && j>=1 && j<4 && i<4)
```

That will make sure you don't reference from your array with a negative index or a value greater than 4.